# Checking your internet connection using speedtest-cli and watch

Tags: linux

I came across this brew command called 'watch', which when executed runs the next command periodically. I decided to use this in conjunction with another brew command called speedtest-cli which checks the internet speed. 
 So, watch has an option called -b or -beep, which beeps whenever the command doesn't execute successfully. When used with speedtest-cli, it beeps when you don't have an internet connection. 
However, I was looking for ways to make it beep when it does execute successfully. Does anyone know a way I could do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can with watch alone.

Comment: Ah okay, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You can install the tool beep and create a script for what you want to do or try `echo -e "\a"` after asking if the last command was successfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three command line ways to accomplish this by putting the suiting command at the end of your script you may invoke for your lengthy process:

1.The "classical" way to play a sound is to use beep Install beep through the PC speakers. However this will not work in all cases (e.g. in my system PC speakers are completely disabled) and you will need to remove pscpkr from /etc/modprobe/blacklist.conf and load the pcspkr kernel module.

```
sudo sed -i 's/blacklist pcspkr/#blacklist pcspkr/g' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo modprobe pcspkr
beep [optional parameters]
```

2.We can also play any sound file in wav format using aplay (installed by default):

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Side_Right.wav
```

3.Another way is to use the pulseaudio command line interface to enable playback of any sound files your system (in libsndfile) recognizes on the default audio output:

```
 paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga

We can use default sound files from /usr/share/sounds/, or any other sound file we may have in a different location.
```

4.You can also use:--

```
make; spd-say done
```

replace make with your command.

5.You can also use espeak(first you have to install it):--

```
espeak "Your Message"
```

I have tested this on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thank you for your commend @Bhavya. I will indeed try those things out :)

Comment: You can appreciate my effort by accepting my answer

Comment: Definitely, I am quite new so I had no idea accepting the answers was a thing